# Prepend table alias to sort by column name?

Tags: collection, order-grid, selection

I am using the `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before` event in order to append a filter to the collection.
However, in my case, I need to `JOIN sales_flat_order` table.
The problem is that the ordering is of the form `ORDER BY created_at`, and both `sales_flat_order_grid` and `sales_flat_order` have this column name..

How can I change/modify it to `main_table.created_at`, for instance?
I'm looking for a systematic method to prepend the table aliases to `ORDER` statements regardless of the specific column used, and, maybe to `GROUP` statements to.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this solution?

```
$select = $collection->getSelect();
$select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
$select->order('main_table.created_at');
```

Comment: It *Appends* an *additional* order by. Additionally, what if the user orders by a *different* column?

Comment: Than you need to check post data to know which filter customer selected.

Comment: Yes correct. But how do I **remove** the original order by? Your solution **adds** another order by

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Nope, The reset does not remove the original order by.

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi - you should include a reference to docs on `Zend_Db_Select::reset` for readers to better understand the answer.